# Force login to access catalog and product pages

Tags: customer, login, product-page, magento-1.9.2

Is there a way to force (simply redirect to login page) the user log-in, to access catalog and product pages?

Comment: Please mention magento version

Comment: you mean do not allow category and product pages unless the customer is logged in?

Comment: @AmitBera, already mentioned the version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php 
    if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        //not logged in
    }else{
        // logged in
    }
?>
```

you can use this code to check.

**For Example :**

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
}
?>
```

put this code at the top of following files.

1) app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

2) app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

Answer (score 3):

Here a few resources that may help you:

- Magento 1 module to require login : https://github.com/jreinke/magento-require-login
- Magento 2 module to require login: https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login