# Magento 2, force login on specific product and specific catalog pages

Tags: magento2, login, category-products

I find this  solution [Magento 2, force login on product and catalog pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188202/magento-2-force-login-on-product-and-catalog-pagesbut) how to verify that your solution is just for a specific Category?? thanks in advance – Developper Magento 22 hours ago